# Elevated permissions are required to set system date? (error 70 permission denied)

Tags: vb6

I have a fairly large (~500 kLOC) machine control application that I maintain, and I'm trying to have several machines on a network synchronize their internal clocks.  (For security reasons, these are on private networks, never to be connected to the Internet.)

I'm successfully retrieving the remote machine time (using `NetRemoteTOD()`), and successfully setting the local time using `Date =` and `Time =` within the IDE.  However, when I run the compiled application, it fails at the Date statement with Error 70 - Permission denied.

I can get around this by running the compiled application either `as Administrator`, or in Compatibility mode as windows XP.  (I'm using Windows 10-Pro.)

I've also tried using the Win-32 `SetLocalTime` API call, because I read [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?807737-RESOLVED-SetSystemTime-API-fails-(Win7-Win8)) that local users have this privilege by default (as opposed to that needed for the `SetSystemTime` call), but the results were the same (worked in the IDE in compatibility mode, and the executable as Administrator but not as a regular process).

I looked at `RtlAdjustPrivilege()`, but that looked like it was rapidly becoming a quagmire, not least because I was having a hard time finding the contant value (in a non-string format) for the privilege I'm looking for (`SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME`, I believe).

So far, there has been nothing else in this application that has required Administrator privileges or compatibility mode, and I'd hate for this to be the first instance thereof - I've got around 350 installations scattered around the world.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Update (not a positive one): I found the constant that I needed, and tried using RtlAdjustPrivilege before the call to SetLocalTime.  Unsurprisingly, it worked under the interpreter (the new RtlAdjustPrivilege call, too), but not as an executable.

Comment: Have you considered using an NTP (Network Time Protocol) Server? There are some free ones available like [Meinberg](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm) which could make all of this effort much easier.

Comment: Possibly your IDE is itself running as administrator which is why it works there.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville - Unfortunately, a NTP solution won't work here, because the application itself is very time-critical; if the time changes while it's running, it can screw up the calculations (rate-of-change) that it's doing for its control function.  Therefore, I want to set the time at start-up only.  However, thanks for the pointer - that could definitely be useful for other applications.

Comment: @DaveInCaz: Yes, that's exactly what's happening, except that the IDE is running in compatibility mode for Windows XP, which evidently allows the time-setting privilege just like as-administrator does.

Comment: Instead of setting the actual system clock, couldn't the instances of your app just persist their local offset from the global system time to their particular local time? Then they can still all operate on the same time basis without requiring a Windows system-level change to the actual clock.

Comment: @DaveInCaz: This had occurred to me; in fact, I did exactly that when I discovered a bug in Microsoft's NTVDM for WindowsOnWindows (WOW) that sets the system clock ahead by one day for one second exactly at midnight, by advancing the date a second early.  This application is a lot larger, and the thought of replacing every call to `Now` with one to `MyNow` is a little daunting.  It's still on the table, though - thanks for the suggestion!